# Fluent NHibernate optimistic lock

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to configure op-locking using fluent nhibernate.

There is a lot of info out there but none seems to fit the scenario I'm in. My class and map are as follows (edited for brevity):

Entity:

```
public class EmailGroup : CRUDDomainObject<EmailGroup>
{        
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual MailServer Server { get; set;}
    public virtual string FromAddress { get; set;}
    public virtual string ToAddress { get; set;}
    public virtual long Version { get; set; }    
}
```

Map:

```
public class EmailGroupMap : ClassMap<EmailGroup>
{
    public const string TABLE_ID = "EMAILGROUP";

    public const string FIELD_ID = "EMAILID";
    public const string FIELD_MAIL_SERVER = "MAILSERVID";
    public const string FIELD_FROM_ADDRESS = "EMLFROM";
    public const string FIELD_TO_ADDRESS = "EMLTO";
    public const string FIELD_VERSION = "VERSION";

    public EmailGroupMap()
    {
        Table(TABLE_ID);

        Id(x => x.Id)
            .Column(FIELD_ID)
            .Not.Nullable()
            .GeneratedBy.Assigned()
            .Length(12);

        References(x => x.Server)
            .Column(FIELD_MAIL_SERVER)
            .NotFound.Ignore();

        Map(x => x.FromAddress)
            .Column(FIELD_FROM_ADDRESS)
            .Not.Nullable()
            .Length(120);

        Map(x => x.ToAddress)
            .Column(FIELD_TO_ADDRESS)
            .Not.Nullable()
            .Length(1000);

        Version(X => X.Version)
            .Column(FIELD_VERSION)
            .Generated.Always()
            .UnsavedValue("0")
            .Access.Property();

        DynamicUpdate();

        OptimisticLock.Version();
    }
}
```

All looks well to me here, but when I load the entity and modify it, the version number is not incremented. Likewise if I manually increment the version, while a session is open, I get no StaleObjectException.

Does this config look valid to the more experienced eye? If so what else could I be missing?

UPDATE:

After implementing a database managed timestamp the version column is (of course) being incremented. However NHibernate doesn't treat the row as optimistically locked. I captured the update query from the SQL server to check the where clause (truncated for brevity):

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [EMAILGROUP] 
SET [EMLDESC] = @EMLDESC, [MAILSERVID] = @MAILSERVID, [EMLFROM] = @EMLFROM, [EMLTO] = @EMLTO, [EMLCC] = @EMLCC, [EMLBCC] = @EMLBCC 
WHERE [EMAILID] = @EMAILID'
```

Comment: Are you sure that there is no convention that overrides part of that mapping? Maybe also search for calls to helper conventions in your code, e.g. `OptimisticLock.Is(<something>)`.

Comment: Thanks cremor, while it wasn't the mapping being overrided it seemed I was testing against the wrong object, while the mapping existed it was not being managed by hibernate. After changing Generated to Never the locking works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why did you specify `Generated.Always()`? That tells NHibernate that this isn't a real column but instead calculated by the database. Documentation: http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-generated

Remove that and it should work.

Comment: Hi cremor, I have amended the line as you are right it was set incorrectly. However it has had no effect.

Comment: This actually was the issue, it transpired I was testing on an unmanaged object.

Answer (score 2):

The most typical scneario for `Version` and SQL Server (not sure if this is your case) is the sql type `timestamp` (obsolete) or better `rowversion`. This should be mapped to C# `byte[]`. So these changes should solve it:

1) Version column on the server must be of type `rowversion` (or `timestamp`). Such a column is automatically updated on any changes related to current row. only one such column can exist per table

2) The entity should look like this

```
public class EmailGroup : CRUDDomainObject<EmailGroup>
{        
   ...
   public virtual byte[] Version { get; set; }
```

3) the fluent mapping code should remain as it is. It should be a job of a fluent mapper to do the tricks behind. what we need to achieve is something like this:

```
<version name="Version" generated="always" unsaved-value="null"  type="BinaryBlob">
    <column name="Version" not-null="false" sql-type="timestamp"/>
</version>
```

Please, see more here: http://ayende.com/blog/3946/nhibernate-mapping-concurrency

Comment: Thanks Radim, while the databse is incrementing the column here on every update NHibernate is still not generating the correct where clause for optimistic locking and not generating a stale object exception leading me to believe the issue is elsewhere. I have updated the question with the generated SQL.

Comment: I cannot see the update. But I would definitely suggest to you, to keep the update of the Version on the server. That will assure, that even if some other process (batch, admin...) will change data, the Version will be different.

Comment: I see the updated now. The only difference I have in my mapping is the Unsaved value, which is NULL for binary blob. Could you check this? Other settings are the same for me (I do expect that you are using `rowversion` instead of `long`)

Comment: Thanks for this Radim, the issue is now resolved. Voted you up as I intend to use this method is phase two.